# Having trouble iterating through a session key and comparing the value to database

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to iterate through a session key I have, collect the values into a list, and then compare it to a database.

I have tried:

```
List<Model> listVar = new List<Model>();
for(int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
{
    int index = arrayValue[i]
    listVar = databasemodel.table.Where(s => s.id == index).ToList()
}
```

It's only grabbing one of the values though when I do this, kinda new to Linq. Is there a method I can use instead of what I am doing now?

Comment: Where do you store the result of your Where expression? Next loop new set of values.

Comment: Sorry, in a list variable I created. Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a simlar issue before, I used the .Contains() method.. as follows:

```
.Where(s => id.Contains(s.id));
```

That should work.

Comment: This works! I will check your answer when I can, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the s.id is an integer then you need to add the results of your WHERE expression to the final list

```
var selectedids = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
{
    int index = arrayValue[i];
    selectedIds.AddRange(databasemodel.table.Where(s => s.id == index));
}
```